# UpdatePanel and Lost Events - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, events, onclick, updatepanel

I'm suffering from events lost after a partial postback, on a user control inside an update panel.  I've searched extensively for a solution for this and I've found lots of jquery event solutions and AsyncPostBackTriggers implementations, but the suggested fixes don't apply to my case or haven't worked.

My scenario is the following:

I have a PageContainer.ascx which contains an Update Panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel_1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
etc..
```

UpdatePanel_1 has inside other user controls as grandchildren, including **Links.ascx**:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlLinksBody" runat="server" class="PRD_BC_box">
   <asp:Repeater ID="repLinks" runat="server" onitemdatabound=" repLinks_ItemDataBound>
        <HeaderTemplate>
              (...)
        </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNumber" runat="server" CssClass="linkMedium NumberLink" OnClick="lnkNumber_OnClick">
                </asp:LinkButton>
                 </td>                        
                 <td>
            </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
```

And my **Links.ascx.cs** has the following:

```
protected void repLinks_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var citationRepeater = item.FindControl("repLinks") as Repeater;
    var citations = getCitations();

    if ((citationRepeater != null) && (citations.Count > 0))
    {
        citationRepeater.DataSource = citations;
        citationRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void lnkNumber_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Server code that needs to be executed
}
```

So when I first load the Links control, the databinding occurs, and each lnkNumber gets the click handler assigned as defined in the template.  After clicking it, a post-back occurs and the lnkNumber_OnClick event is fired correctly.  However, the second time clicking it, the event is never fired.

I understand that Update Panels and their partial postbacks re-write code and the events need to be re-wired to work again, however nothing I've tried seems to work.

I have tried:

- From the Links.ascx.cs, get the grandparent UpdatePanel from PageContainer and add to it an AsyncPostBackTrigger with CliendId = pnlLinksBody. (can't add a trigger for each LinkButton since their ID is auto-generated during dataBind)
- Changing the LinkButtons properties - useSubmitBehavior true/false
- Calling updatePanel_1.Update() after each post-back.

And also,

- The firstLinks control load happens during a post-back, so doing something like "if (!IsPostBack) DataBind();"  would not work to prevent re-bindings.
- The Update Panel's updateMode and childrenAsTriggers properties cannot be changed, since that would affect other components' behavior.
- The link's click event logic needs to be server side.

Does anyone have any suggestions which I might try to re-bind the click events?

I appreciate the help!